# IE11 TLS seems to have issues, but no idea why

Tags: ssl, internet-explorer-11, tls, browsing

I found my computer couldn't reach the openbsd.org website, IE11 on Windows 8.1 reported a TLS issue, but all TLS were working and no other website gave a similar error. I found "solutions" saying to re-enable SSL2+3 (which is certainly not the answer so I didn't!)

So I tried another computer, and exactly the same thing happened.

Developer tools just showed it failed to connect, but no details, so I tried to check where the error was happening using the [OpenSSL website SSL tester and entering "openbsd.org"](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.openbsd.org).

Results:

```
Handshake Simulation

Chrome 49 / XP SP3  RSA 4096 (SHA256)    TLS 1.2    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256   ECDH secp256r1   FS
Chrome 57 / Win 7  R     RSA 4096 (SHA256)    TLS 1.2    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256   ECDH x25519   FS
Firefox 31.3.0 ESR / Win 7  RSA 4096 (SHA256)    TLS 1.2    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256   ECDH secp256r1   FS
Firefox 47 / Win 7  R    RSA 4096 (SHA256)    TLS 1.2    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256   ECDH secp256r1   FS
Firefox 49 / XP SP3  RSA 4096 (SHA256)    TLS 1.2    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256   ECDH secp256r1   FS
Firefox 53 / Win 7  R    RSA 4096 (SHA256)    TLS 1.2    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256   ECDH x25519   FS
IE 8-10 / Win 7  R   Server sent fatal alert: protocol_version
IE 11 / Win 7  R     Server sent fatal alert: handshake_failure
IE 11 / Win 8.1  R   Server sent fatal alert: handshake_failure
IE 11 / Win 10  R    RSA 4096 (SHA256)    TLS 1.2
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384   ECDH secp256r1   FS
```

So they found that it wasn't working with IE11 on Win 8.1 either. Given OpenBSD's reputation I would find it hard to believe it's any kind of misconfiguration of their server, in which case I'm left puzzled.

How can I check what's actually happening? Is the website blocked from IE11/Win8.1 "full stop", and is there a fix other than "use a different browser"?

Comment: In the SSLLabs report you cite you can see that only 4 ciphers are supported by the server. Each of these ciphers is a secure one but none of these is supported with IE11 on 8.1 :(

Comment: I believe this is due to only TLS 1.2 being enabled.  I would need to dig up a proper answer, but if my understanding is correct the ciphers supported by IE 10 and earlier don't have a single cipher in common with default ciphers shipped with typical TLS 1.2 suites, thus older browsers don't have a common cipher to connect with.  I think you would also see the same handshake results with TLS 1.0 disabled, and 1.1 and 1.2 enabled.

Comment: IE11 not 10. Still current on any 8.1.Can additional ciphers be added that aren't already in it? Is the site's TLS cipher policy actually designed to completely block Win 8.1 unless used with a 3rd party browser then (by design, or as a definitive byproduct of high level security?)